# From the water to the door

Tags: darksiders

#### Warning: pic heavy

I'm on my way to my second encounter with Griever. I just retrieved the Tremor Gauntlet and finished the train depot section.

Now, I knew I thought where I should be going next. There was a crystal blockage in the cathedral and with the new Tremor Gauntlet in hand that was the next logical place to go.

[image: crystal blockage]

Behind the door, there's a small piece of hallway and a bunch of water. In the water are two floating platforms. It appears you can't return from the platform since the height is too much.

[image: first platform]

I suppose one should jump down, get to the second platform and somehow reach the next door. Problem is, the door seems out of reach.

[image: target door]

Overview of my current location, for good measure.

[image: location]

Now either I'm in the correct place at the wrong time (too early) or I'm just not seeing a way out where there is one. It looks impossible to get back to the door where I came from, but old save-games help with that.

Now, now do I get to that door?

Comment: I could easily answer this when I'm at a computer - but only given how incredibly easy it is to find that information online. You've just received the tremor gloves. On your way to the second fight with Griever. Sounds like a very specific part of a Darksiders walk-through would tell you where to go. I definitely didn't have a choke point here in my play through, but I would try jumping in the water, or seeing what's around the corner, where the map shows that area to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit crystal switches on these cubes to make them rise then quickly jump onto it.

You should be able to reach the doors from the floating cube.

[Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/darksiders/Hollows,_East_Part_I)

Comment: The issue that people often get confused with is what to use to hit the switches. Up to this point, the only tool people have used (or suggested to have used) is the Crossblade, which of course, doesn't travel through water. I would suggest specifying that you can hit this with the sword while swimming.

Answer (score 1):

The reason I posted this here was because I didn't figure out in time the crystal switches could be hit by pretty much anything. So far the obvious way to hit them was with your throwing weapon. Those don't work under water.

Your sword does. As PapaStan indicated, hit the switch on the second block (closest to your destination), jump up and lift out of the water with the rising block. When the block is at it's highest, jump towards the door and glide the remainder.

Comment: I encountered this issue twice. First in the original, and then again in the "Warmastered" edition. It took me almost an hour to figure it out the first time, then thankfully, due to a hazy memory, only 20 minutes the second time around.